# How to start learning AI?

Tags: machine-learning

I’m gonna start a bachelor's degree in CS in November, and I would like to focus further on AI to work in this field.
The thing is, in my university most of the courses in AI are taken in master's degree, and I would like to study independently AI to get started in AI before completing my bachelor's degree.

1. What topics will I need to learn to start writing AI project  independently ( a type of portfolio for the company).
2. What does the interviewer focus on in a job interview?
3. I would love to get links to recommended courses / books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start learning Machine Learning (a subset from AI):

- CS229: Machine Learning. http://cs229.stanford.edu/.
- Deep Learning An MIT Press book. https://www.deeplearningbook.org/

Here you can find some useful Python tutorials:
 - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/artificial_intelligence_with_python/index.htm

And a course: https://www.udacity.com/course/ai-programming-python-nanodegree--nd089

Here you can find some resources for deeplearning (but I suggest you start with machine learning first):

- http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/
- https://www.guru99.com/deep-learning-tutorial.html
- https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/deep-learning-python
- https://openai.com/resources/

The interview process changes from company to company, but it can involve some basic questions:

- https://career.guru99.com/top-50-interview-questions-on-artificial-intelligence/
- https://www.springboard.com/blog/artificial-intelligence-questions/
- https://intellipaat.com/blog/interview-question/artificial-intelligence-interview-questions/
- https://www.edureka.co/blog/interview-questions/artificial-intelligence-interview-questions/

It depends on the profile the company is looking for. A trading company can look for you to have knowledge about Markov chains and sequence predictions.

You should start with the basics. It is a broad field and it takes time to develop a career in these subjects.